# alexa ask sdk v2 nodejs how to speak out array of strings in response

Tags: node.js, response, alexa-skills-kit, ssml

I am having problems speaking out multiple options in the alexa response. Please find the code below:

```
let results = await getNearestNames(data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);      
// generate response
let nearestNames = "";
results.map((obj) => {
    nearestNames += obj.name + '<break time="1s">';
});

response = responseBuilder
    .speak(nearestNames)
    .getResponse();
```

The getNearestNames API call sends an array in response. I am trying to speak out each one of the name one by one. But passing the nearestNames variable to the speak() functions results in "There s problem with requested skill's response". How do I resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the below code to send multiple responses, it makes an API call to fetch book names, iterate over it and responds back with the title. It uses the [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native) module to make the request, just to show the example.

```
async function getNames() {
  try {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://libgen.io/json.php?ids=1,2&fields=Title,Author,MD5"
    };
    let result = await rp(options);
    result = JSON.parse(result);
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
}

const BookNameIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return (
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest" &&
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "BookIntent"
    );
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const data = await getNames();
    let names = "";
    data.map(item => {
      names += `${item.title} <break time="3s"/>`;
    });
    console.log("Names ", names);
    const speechText = `<speak> The books names are, <break time="2s"/> ${names}</speak>`;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Alexa's resposnes are not developer friendly when something went wrong, are they?

This error is probably caused by exception thrown by `getNearestNames` method (add `.catch(e => console.log(e))` and check CloudWatch output, or due to too long response time - you've got only 10 seconds to react for User's input, or you've just haven't marked handler's method as `async`. Also I am not sure if Alexa wraps response text with `<speak>` markups - you are using `<break>` in your sample.